# Show, that $h$ can be continuous when both sets are open or both sets are closed.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In Lipschutz's "outline of theory and problems of general topology" the following problem is posed:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces with $X = E \cup F$. Let $f:E \rightarrow Y$ and $g:F \rightarrow Y$ with $f=g$ on $E \cap F$ de continuous functions with respect to the relative topologies. Note that $h = f \cup g$ is a function from $X$ into $Y$. (i) Show by an example that $h$ need not be continuous. (ii) Prove that if $E$ and $F$ are both open then $h$ is continuous. (iii) Prove that if $E$ and $F$ are bith closed then $h$ is continuous.

For (i) i thought about the following example.

$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} := \begin{cases}
1, & \text{for } (-\infty, 0)\\
0, & \text{for } [0, \infty)
\end{cases}
$$
Which is not continous at $0$.

I am having trouble proving (ii) and (iii). If both cases were open, for example
$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} := \begin{cases}
1, & \text{for } (-\infty, 0)\\
0, & \text{for } (0, \infty)
\end{cases}
$$
i think that it would still be discontinous at 0 and i don't think i could do the same thing for a closed counterpart. Is my approach to this problem right? How do i go about proving (ii) and (iii)? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second function $f$ doesn't make sense: you claim that it is a function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$, but it is undefined at $0$.

(ii) Let $A$ be an open subset of $Y$. Then $f^{-1}(A)=(f|_X)^{-1}(A)\cup(f|_Y)^{-1}(A)$, which is the union of two open sets, and therefore it is an open set. So, $f$ is continuous.

(iii) Let $A$ be a closed subset of $Y$. Then $f^{-1}(A)=(f|_X)^{-1}(A)\cup(f|_Y)^{-1}(A)$, which is the union of two closed sets, and therefore it is a closed set. So, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: thanks a lot, you are right about the second f not being a function and the answers to (ii) and (iii) are simpler than i thought.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.